# Issue with passing reference of variable

Tags: php

```
<?php 
function requestSecond($param) {
    $param['conf']++;
}

function requestFirst($params) {
    $params['conf']++;
    requestSecond($params);
}

$conf = 1;
requestFirst(array(
    'conf' => &$conf,
));
echo $conf;
```

Result: `3`

Question:

I know `&$conf` means pass the reference of `$conf`, so I understand after `requestFirst($params)`, `$conf=2`, but i do not understand why after `requestSecond($param)`, `$conf=3`, `requestSecond($param);` does this also pass reference of `$conf` not value?

Comment: `var_dump($param)` in the `requestSecond` function and see what you get. If you see an ampersand (`&`) it's also passed by reference.

Comment: In my opinion you are passing &$conf pass by reference to both functions thats why you are getting 3. actually in requestsecond($param) you are passing same variable &$conf that you passed in requestfirst.

Comment: Passing stuff by reference usually is a bad thing because of such ambiguities. Avoid it. In PHP5 there is a clear definition: Objects are always passed as reference, anything else is passed as a copy (that gets only created if you write to it, otherwise it is not copied in memory).

Comment: There's no ambiguity here he's passing as value both times, the value he's passing is a reference held in the array.

Comment: The ambiguity is in the effects of the code. When I look at `requestSecond()`, there is no hint of it affecting `$conf`. And when I look at `requestFirst()`, there is also no hint of such effect. So I wonder why the array element is actually incremented, and not given back. Only if I look at the array that is passed I realize that it contains a channel back out of the functions. THIS is the ambiguity, because it won't happen with a normal array. The code does exactly what should be done, but it's effects depend on a tiny little difference in the data it works on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$conf` in requestFirst is reference, It will still be reference when you pass it to new function. It will be reference even if you assign it to local variable inside requestFirst.

eg:

```
function requestFirst($params) {
  $params['conf']++;    
  $stillReference = $params; // $stillReference will also hold reference to $conf
  $local = array( 'conf' => $params['conf']); // This will be local and the output will be 2
  requestSecond($stillReference); //outputs 3
}
```

In above example there is no difference between `$params` and `$stillReference` and both are using the same internal variable container. The only way to separate these two is by invalidating one of the variables using `unset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$conf` in `requestFirst` is reference, so if you use that variable on new callings, it is still reference.

If you use `var_dump($params)` your will see that `conf` is reference `array(1) {["conf"] => &int(2)}`

Answer (score 0):

The array holds a reference to $conf it is this that you are passing.

i.e. you have an array with one element 'conf' which is a reference to $conf so when you call `$param['conf']++` you are calling ++ on the referenced $conf not the array which HAS been passed by value. Both your functions take params by value btw.

i think your confusion comes in that `&$conf` does mean reference of `$conf` but you are assigning this to the array element not passing it as a reference to `requestFirst($params)` if you wanted requestFirst to take a reference rather than a value you would use `requestFirst(&$foo)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`requestFirst` is passing a lightweight copy of the argument array to `requestSecond` as you expect. But since the original argument contains a *reference* to `$conf`, the copy contains a reference as well. So when you modify that particular element the change is visible through all other references to the `$conf` variable as well:

```
function requestSecond($param) {
    $param['conf']++;     // change to the int counter happens here
}

function requestFirst($params) {
    $params['conf']++;
    requestSecond($params);
    echo $params['conf']; // change is visible here
}

$conf = 1;
requestFirst(array(
    'conf' => &$conf,
));
echo $conf;               // change also visible here
```

However, `$param` itself is still a copy of `$params` and any changes made to it will not be visible outside the scope of `requestSecond`:

```
function requestSecond($param) {
    $param['conf']++;
    $param['foo'] = 'bar';
}

function requestFirst($params) {
    $params['conf']++;
    requestSecond($params);
    echo (int)isset($params['foo']); // "0" -- change not visible
}
```

You could even *remove* the reference from the array after incrementing it; the change to the referenced counter would remain, and the change to the array would not:

```
function requestSecond($param) {
    $param['conf']++;

    // remove the reference from the array -- this will only affect
    // the local copy $param and nothing else
    unset($param['conf']);
}

function requestFirst($params) {
    $params['conf']++;
    requestSecond($params);
    echo $params['conf']; // 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `requestSecond($params);`, `$params` is the argument you pass to `requestFirst`. You're passing a reference to an int, so your second function will also receive this reference. That's why the variable is updated two times.